# Android adb constantly shows "authorizing" for connected physical device

Tags: android, adb, usb-debugging

I am using adb to connect to my physical device. Everything worked for a while, now all of a sudden adb tells me it would be "authorizing" all the time. I have already restarted adb, restarted the physical device, restarted USB debugging on the device but nothing helped.

When I run `adb devices` it keeps telling me

```
List of devices attached
42b406de    authorizing
```

With this, I can not remote debug the device, can not even open the developer menu in the app I want to debug (for opening the developer menu, I use `adb shell input keyevent 82` and that returns `adb: device still authorizing`.

Does anyone have a hint on what to do in such case to get debugging running again?

Thanks and best regards

EDIT: Maybe also important - I am using adb on Mac OS Big Sur

Comment: Did you clear authorized devices in Android Developer Settings and triggered the authorization process again?

Comment: yes, same result, unfortunately

Comment: Did the authorization pop up on the Android Device appeard and did you accept it?

Comment: It had appeared by the time that I had authorized. Then, all of a sudden, it said „authorizing“ even though it had been already authorized but the popup did not show up again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got this fixed by completely resetting the debug mode on the device and then unplugging and replugging the device to USB

Comment: Can you please explain more on "resetting the debug mode". I am also having the same issue but couldn't find a solution

Comment: @SritejaSugoor It's done by clicking the `Revoke USB debugging authorizations` under Developer Options

Comment: Actually that also didn't work for me. What worked is to restart laptop